# Prevent SQL double booking

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to prevent double booking in a booking system, C# to SQL Server.

I'm using stored procedures and tried this:

```
alter proc Datumkoll
    @DatumFrom smalldatetime = null,
    @datumTill smalldatetime = null
as
    select RumsNummer 
    from rum 
    where 
        RumsNummer not in (select rumsnummer 
                           from rumsbokning 
                           where datumfrån >= @datumfrom and datumtill <= @datumTill)

 GO
```

This code will not prevent double booking if the date is set within an already existing booking

Comment: Selecting rooms that aren't currently booked won't prevent double booking. Unless, of course, your database engine does not support concurrency or you are using some very pessimistic locking strategy. Its the code where you create the booking that will matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select R.RumsNummer
from rum R
where not exists (
            select RB.rumsnummer
            from rumsbokning RB
            where 
                R.RumId = RB.RumId
                and RB.datumfrån >= @datumfrom 
                and RB.datumtill <= @datumTill )
```

Anyway, you should perform this check again when you're saving a new booking.

Answer (score 2):

Picture the time-windows and the options:

non-overlapping:

```
[new]
         [existing]
```

partial overlapping:

```
[new]                 [new]
  [existing]   [existing]
```

containment:

```
    [new]       [-------new---------]
  [existing]         [existing]
```

Your check only handles the last of these; you need to go back and consider the others. The trick is that there are actually only 3 tests needed:

- the new start date is in an existing booking
- the new end date is in an existing booking
- and existing booking is *entirely* inside the new booking

which gives us:

```
where (datumfrån>=@datumfrom and datumtill <= @datumTill)
or (@datumfrom >= datumfrån and @datumfrom <= datumtill)
or (@datumTill >= datumfrån and @datumfrom <= datumtill)
```

(see also the comments for alternative constructions)

Comment: It can be simplified to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) - `datumfrån <= @datumTill and datumtill >= @datumfrom`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I wasn't convinced initially, but on inspection - that seems valid

Comment: Assuming `datefrom > datetill` and `@dateFrom > @dateTill` are both always true, then non-conflicting booking are `@dateTill<dateFrom OR datetill<@dateFrom` (ie. either completely to the left, or completely to the right). Negating that gives you the conflicts...

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, this formula gives overlapping ranges. I should have negated it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  Select rumsnummer 
   from rumsbokning 
   where datumfrån <= @datumTill and datumtill >= @datumfrom
```